# Matlab graphics do not update in successive runs

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created a matlab figure plot and then plotted several rectangles.

```
for i=1:size(rect,2)/2
        rectangle('Position',[rect(i)-1,rect(i+2*size(rect,2)),5,2])
end
```

Now i want to loop them thru a for-loop simulating the passage of time.

```
    daspect([1,1,1])

    for t=0:0.1:6.28
        for i=1:size(rect,2)/2
                rectangle('Position',[rect(i)-1-2*sint(t),rect(i+2*size(rect,2))-2*sin(t),5,2])
        end
        pause(0.1)
    end
```

The trouble with the rectangle command is that for `t=0`, the figures are good but for `t=0.1`, the new figures overlap with figures of `t=0` thus spoiling the graphics. What is the fix? I am not even using `hold on`.

Comment: Did you want the different timepoints on different figures?

Comment: No, on the same figure i want different time-frames to replace the previous time-frame and get plotted, just like a film video.

Comment: a few answers are here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/84738-how-to-clear-data-from-plot-in-matlab-gui

Comment: what's with the downvote though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `findobj` to look for rectangles and delete them as new ones appear?

```
for t=0:0.1:6.28
        for i=1:size(rect,2)/2

            hRect = findobj('Type','rectangle')
            delete(hRect)

            rectangle('Position',[rect(i)-1-2*sint(t),rect(i+2*size(rect,2))-2*sin(t),5,2])
        end
        pause(0.1)
    end
```

Comment: It worked though i had to place the lines a bit differently.line 3,4 went in between line 1 & 2.

Comment: awesome then glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work to clear the rectangle before plotting the next one

```
for t=0:0.1:6.28
    delete(h)
    for i=1:size(rect,2)/2
            h=rectangle('Position',[rect(i)-1-2*sint(t),rect(i+2*size(rect,2))-2*sin(t),5,2])
    end
    pause(0.1)
end
```